# How to Upgrade Firebase Crash Reporting to Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

Unable to build my project. showing error message

Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found.

Error:(62, 13) Failed to resolve: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1

Steps followed

[image]

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-from-crash-reporting

[image]

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#14

If anyone have any idea please share your idea.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

make some change in dependency ..

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project lavel dependency

```
  repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: Same error Error:(72, 13) Failed to resolve: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1
And Error:(71, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0

Comment: Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())
      define in main activity in oncreate method.

Comment: Tried this Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())                                                           compilation error cannot resolve Fabric class

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the line that gave me the error was this one:

> classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'

When I switched to

> classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'

it compiled correctly

I've found the updated lines of code here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started